# switch identifiers in spark to pseudonymize dataset

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe like:

```
+---+-----+
| id|value|
+---+-----+
|  a|    1|
|  a|    2|
|  b|    1|
|  b|    3|
+---+-----+
val df = Seq(("a", 1), ("a", 2), ("b", 1), ("b", 3)).toDF("id", "value")
```

How can I efficiently switch / rotate IDs. Note, hashing is not what I want here, I explicitly want to rotated the identifiers. How could this be implemented in spark efficiently without a self join? Maybe some `RDD zipWithIndex`?

Not: my intention is to pseudonyme / anonymize the dataset by rotating identifiers. My requirement is to replace each `a` with another identifier, i.e. possibly `b`. They all need to be replaced to the same value.

### edit

I had a first suggestion: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-features.html#stringindexer but this would change data types and also not rotate identifiers something I want to prevent. I need a drop in but anon- /pseudo-nymized replacement.

Also, I expect about 8 million (constant) distinct values for ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Collecting all distinct elements and building a map using zip with a randomly permutated list of these distinct elements works.